# Using imakeidx with custom page numbering

Tags: page-numbering, indexing

I am using the `imakeidx` package to generate an index for some course notes. The problem is that the document uses a different page numbering system: it is divided into "lectures" and numbers the pages within the lecture

```
\numberwithin{page}{lecture}
```

This causes `imakeidx` (and plain `makeidx`) to quit working. Any thoughts for how I can get around this?

Edit: here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\numberwithin{page}{section}
\begin{document}
Test\index{Test1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Compiling this produces no errors but does not generate an index. Commenting out line number 5 (`\numberwithin{page}{section}`) causes the index to be generated.

Comment: `quit working` is not really helpful. Can you provide us with a minimal working document that shows this feature?

Comment: Sure. See edited post.

Comment: MakeIndex is not able to deal with complex page numbers, so it rejects entries with something like `1.2` as page number. Do you plan to have subitems?

Comment: egreg: It would be great to have the option for subitems in the index. However I'll settle for not having them if necessary.

Comment: This is a MakeIndex problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to provide some support for sorting even for page numbers that aren't just normal figures, but setting the `page_compositor "."` tag in a `makeindex` `.ist` file, assuming that no more than one dot occurs in the output.

The document writes a `pagesection.ist` index style file with the relevant settings and uses `imakeidx` with the `options=-s pagesection.ist` key to apply this file to the `makeindex` run.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\makeindex[name=pagesection,title={List of something},options=-s pagesection.ist]

\begin{filecontents}{pagesection.ist}
page_precedence "nrRAa"
page_compositor "."
\end{filecontents}

\numberwithin{page}{section}
\begin{document}

\section{Foo section}
Test\index[pagesection]{Test1}
\index[pagesection]{Test2}
\index[pagesection]{foo!bar}


\blindtext[5]
\index[pagesection]{Test2}

\blindtext[10]

\index[pagesection]{foo!bar}

\printindex[pagesection]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A related question is [Index by section.subsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352759/index-by-section-subsection/352765#352765)