# Index by section.subsection

Tags: indexing

I am using revtex4-1 in a document with many short subsections (2-3 per page). Rather than the page number, I would like my index to refer to the section and subsection (i.e. "example, 2.1" for the item 'example' in section 2, subsection 1). The code below does everything I want, except there is no "." between the section and subsection numbers:

```
\documentclass[rmp]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeatletter
  \def\@wrindex#1{%
    \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{\thesubsection}}
    \endgroup
  \@esphack}
\makeindex

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section} This is Section 1
\subsection{Subsection} This is Subsection 1.1 \index{My Subsection}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

If I instead do `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}`, then the index will not print. I have seen workarounds such as [this one](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14334), but this method only works for up to 9 subsections. How can I have the index print section.subsection?

Comment: makeindex does not understand the `.` in the index entry

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298519/using-imakeidx-with-custom-page-numbering/352559#352559

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to either change `\thesubsection` into a form that makeindex does understand? Or a way to change what makeindex can understand?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `page_compositor` key is responsible how `makeindex` interpretes the 'numbers' it reads and sorts accordingly.

By defining a new index style file, say `subsection.ist` this can be used to change the key to `.`, for example.

```
\documentclass[rmp]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeatletter
  \def\@wrindex#1{%
    \protected@write\@indexfile{}%
      {\string\indexentry{#1}{\thesubsection}}
    \endgroup
  \@esphack}
\makeindex

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}


\begin{filecontents}{subsection.ist}
page_precedence "nrRAa"
page_compositor "."
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{pgffor}



\begin{document}

\section{Section} This is Section 1
\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
\clearpage
\subsection{Subsection \x} \index{My Subsection}
}

\section{Section} This is Section 1
\foreach \x in {1,...,20} {%
\clearpage
\subsection{Subsection \x} \index{My Subsection}
}


\printindex
\end{document}
```

Call `makeindex -s subsection.ist foo`, if `foo.tex` is the name of the `.tex` document.

[image]

Comment: Please note that `makeindex` is limited in it's parsing and sorting features. `xindy` is by far more elaborate